# The difference between kQdot and kV when computing the Jacobians

Tags: drake

What is the difference between the Jacobian w.r.t `kQdot` and `kv` from trajectory optimization perspective as in [Jacobian methods in Drake](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.plant.html?highlight=calcjacobianspatialvelocity#pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity?).

In my case, I have defined the contact Jacobians between two floating rigidbodies. And I used `CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity` to map contact force to generalized forces.

In a system, we have the state as `[q v]`. I think I understand the `kv` option, but what is for the `kQdot` used for. Are there any examples showing the use case with `kQdot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `kQdot` is more akin to a partial derivative; it is often used in optimization (e.g. to know how to change `q` to improve some objective).  For instance, you'll find lot of uses in the `drake/multibody/inverse_kinematics` folder.

I have some notes about this topic [here](https://manipulation.mit.edu/pick.html#jacobian), including some discussion on qdot vs v.